# How to convert a TensorFlow tensor to a NumPy array within tf.Dataset.map() while multithreading/multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

I use TensorFlow 1.12 in eager execution. I have a computationally expensive function which I map onto this dataset using `tf.Dataset.map()`. Inside this function — which I developed by simply for-looping over the dataset in eager execution — I convert the tensors to NumPy arrays using `EagerTensor.numpy()`. Since preprocessing my dataset takes too long, I now wish to multithread this whole map procedure, using `tf.Dataset.map(myfunction, num_cores=30)`. However, now `myfunction()` isnt being executed eagerly anymore. I tried two things: 1) wrapping `myfunction()` using `tf.py_function`, in which case `map()` isnt being multithreaded anymore, and 2) opening a `tf.Session` inside `myfunction()` and getting my NumPy array using `.eval()` instead of `.numpy()`, in which case I need to supply input tensors (I dont understand why):

````
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'arg0' with dtype string
     [[node arg0 (defined at /home/.../semantic_fpn.py:101)  = Placeholder[dtype=DT_STRING, shape=<unknown>]]```

Is there an easy why for me to loop over my dataset with ```myfunction()``` (and its NumPy conversion) while multithreading/multiprocessing? I had additionally considered using a for-loop instead of ```.map()```, but I wouldn't know how to alter/write to records in a ```tf.Dataset```.
````